# How to convert string to int in C#

Tags: c#

Sorry, I am new to C#.  I am getting a value for quantity from sqlserver. Usually, it comes as a decimal string. For example as "6.00". I have to store it as an int in a C# variable. I am doing the following which worked in a few rows of data I have tested:

```
int newVal = 
    Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDecimal(drUsers["quantity"].ToString()));
```

If I convert directly to int without converting it first to decimal then it throws "Input not in correct format" error. Is there a better way of doing it, especially to handle data errors such as null coming from the database.

Thanks

Comment: If it's already a number in the database, you might just be able to cast it. Have you tried that?

Comment: `TryParse` will return `false` if the conversion fails, which will allow you to handle invalid data without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for sure that the value you're getting is going to be a decimal you could just use

`int newVal = (int)Decimal.Parse(drUsers["quantity"]);`

If you want to be safe and program defensively, I'd suggest using `Decimal.TryParse()` something along the lines of:

```
decimal foo = 0;
int newVal = 0;

if(Decimal.TryParse(drUsers["quantity"], out foo) {
    newVal = (int)foo;
} else {
    //handle error
}
```

EDIT: switched double to decimal, but I think the choice depends on the accuracy you need with the decimal. Database types don’t always match 1:1 with types in c# so either should be okay.

Comment: If it's already a Decimal, wouldn't it be safer to use Decimal.Parse?

Comment: It depends on what the data looks like from the database. If it's a short decimal like "4.243" then Double will suffice, but if it's something _"extreme"_ like "4.2342353252234232423435143621345435343234234" you'll probably want to use Decimal.Parse for higher accuracy. http://net-informations.com/q/faq/float.html here's a little more information on the differences.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the `ToSring()`. You can get the `quantity` as a decimal using the [Field method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataRowExtensions_Field__1_System_Data_DataRow_System_String_).

```cs
Convert.ToInt32(drUsers.Field<decimal>("quantity"));
```